# Dual Citizenship - What Passport Do I Show Entering and Exiting Switzerland?

Tags: passports

I'm leaving the U.S. for a two-months stay in Switzerland this summer.  I have dual citizenship, U.S. and German; I'm departing the U.S for Switzerland with German passport and returning from Switzerland to the U.S. with U.S. passport.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Lorelei. I think the above question and answer will tell you what you need to know. If there is something specific that isn't covered, please edit the question to ask about that.

Comment: I always check in for flights from the US to the EU or Schengen area with my EU passport.  I almost always fly with EU airlines, and I have never been asked about my immigration status in the US.  Some airlines might do so, however, at which point you can show them your US passport.  I've seen at least one message on this site describing such an encounter.  Once I'm on the plane, I put away my US passport until I check in for the return flight to the US. After doing that, I show my EU passport to the immigration officer at Schengen exit control, and then I put it away for the rest of the trip.

Answer (score 2):

Almost correct.

- On the way to Switzerland, you show the German passport.
- On the way to the US, you show the US passport to the airline and US *immigration*, but you show the German passport to Swiss *emigration*.

That's because you won't have an entry stamp on your US passport. The US passport would need one, the German passport doesn't. Having those two passports isn't illegal, so you can show the other passport whenever someone wonders.